# Binary search tree for strings

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been doing a bit of research and can't for the life in me find out if this is possible. Is it possible to use a binary search tree for strings? The way I see it is, if I was to use a binary search tree for strings I'd have to represent those strings with numbers to validate the comparing. I know it's probably better to use a Suffix tree, but if I was to use a binary search tree for strings, what would be the best method for comparing string values such as names? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is no other way besides what you already said, the other way would be to decompose the string and use part of the string as a key, this is very common in databases, althought not very recommended.